# In the following SAS statement, what do the parameters "noobs" and "label" stand for?

Tags: sas

In the following SAS statement, what do the parameters "noobs" and "label" stand for?

```
proc print data-sasuser.schedule noobs label;
```

Comment: dammit, i've always wanted to answer a question about 'noobs' with some sort of smart-arse remark about it being a setting for beginners to SAS... missed the opportunity here!

Comment: ya gotta wonder who put that in the code as a param.. strange sense of humor.. or humour as the case may be..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

per [SAS 9.2 documentation on PROC PRINT](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002291718.htm):

"NOOBS - Suppress the column in the output that identifies each observation by number"

"LABEL - Use variables' labels as column headings"

Answer (score -2):

noobs don't show you the column of observations number
(1,2,3,4,5,....)
my first title 
results without noobs

Obs name sex group height weight 
1 mike m a 21 150 
2 henry m b 30 140 
3 norian f b 18 130 
4 nadine f b 32 135 
5 dianne f a 23 135

results with noobs

---

my first title

name sex group height weight 
mike m a 21 150 
henry m b 30 140 
norian f b 18 130 
nadine f b 32 135 
dianne f a 23 135